# How can I run a Node.js server in HTTPS without a private key?

Tags: node.js, https, server, certificate, private-key

I have a Node.js server over HTTP. I want to run it over HTTPS. To do so I only have the certificate but no private key.

How can I run it over HTTPS without the private key?

Comment: Is it a self-generated certificate?

Comment: Imagine if that could work - you'd be able to download any certificate from a website and then impersonate that site.  Equally, someone else could do it, to your bank for example. The Internet would be an even more dangerous place!  It's the private key (held securely) that makes PKI work - maybe time for some revision?

Comment: That is a self-generated certificate that cannot be created by someone else